# Creating Emails via PHP with WHM/Cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

I am using WHM/Cpanel to manage my sites. I am on a VPS server on Hostgator. I want to create email accounts dynamically via PHP. Does anyone know what I might need in order to do this ? Any good resources ?? Books or code they can share for me to go about doing this ?

I am only dealing with one cpanel account, not multiple accounts, so I figured i would just need the cpanels API.

Comment: It is a matter of application (WHM), if you want to send emails via app (whm), better take a look at whm's documentation. If you want to simply run a php script to send your email, you have nothing to do with whm app. I think you should place to your question in  http://stackapps.com/

Comment: I edited my question. I want to create email accounts only. not send emails. I think this is my confusion. WHM allocates website space but cpanel is what truely manages email accounts. So wouldnt I just use cpanel API instead of WHM. I don't mind reading the documentation to get myself going I guess. Its a matter which API do I use to get what I need done. I am only dealing with one CPANEL account, not multiple cpanel accounts.

Answer (score 2):

The following posts contain some detailed explanation of this:

http://forums.cpanel.net/f42/create-email-account-using-api-121741.html

Using cPanel-Matt's XMLAPI php class is the recommended way to do this which you can find here:

http://forums.cpanel.net/f42/xmlapi-php-class-111897.html